# Error thrown trying to run next.js with express in local development environment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I am trying to set up next.js with express and node.js. The terminal an error when trying to run to local server with express and node. I get the following error when 'npm run dev' is used on the command line.

Package.json:

```
  {
    "name": "nextjs",
    "description": "NextJS Tutorial",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
      "dev": "node server/index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
      "babel-plugin-module-resolver":   "^3.1.1",
      "babel-plugin-wrap-in-js":  "^1.1.1",
      "express": "^4.16.4",
      "next": "^7.0.2",
      "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
      "postcss-easy-import": "^3.0.0",
      "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
      "raw-loader": "^1.0.0",
      "react": "^16.7.0",
      "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
      "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
      "tailwindcss": "^0.7.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "^9.4.5"
    }
  }
```

My server/index.js is as follows:

```
  const express = require('express');
  const next = require('next');

  const PORT = process.env.PORT ||  3000;
  const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !==  'production';
  const app = next({ dev });
  const handle =  app.getRequestHandler();

  app
  .prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    server.get('*', (req,res) => {
      return handle(req,res);
    });


    server.listen(PORT, () => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('> Ready on   ${PORT}');
    });
  })
```

Error log is as follows:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/hvnwntw8/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/hvnwntw8/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.5.0
3 info using node@v10.14.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle nextjs@1.0.0~predev: nextjs@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle nextjs@1.0.0~dev: nextjs@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle nextjs@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle nextjs@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /Users/hvnwntw8/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/hvnwntw8/Projects/nextjs/node_modules/.bin:/Users/hvnwntw8/.rbenv/shims:/Users/hvnwntw8/.global-modules/bin:/Users/hvnwntw8/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin:/Users/hvnwntw8/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin:/opt/yarn-[1.12.3]/bin
9 verbose lifecycle nextjs@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /Users/hvnwntw8/Projects/nextjs
10 silly lifecycle nextjs@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'node sever/index.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle nextjs@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle nextjs@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: nextjs@1.0.0 dev: `node sever/index.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/hvnwntw8/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/hvnwntw8/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid nextjs@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/hvnwntw8/Projects/nextjs
16 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/hvnwntw8/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin/node" "/Users/hvnwntw8/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.1/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v10.14.1
19 verbose npm  v6.5.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error nextjs@1.0.0 dev: `node sever/index.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the nextjs@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried 'npm clean cache -f' followed by 'npm verify', deleting my package-lock.json and node modules folder and running 'npm install' in the terminal. Still no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hey Ryan, Sean here: check this out in the log you provided `22 error nextjs@1.0.0 dev: `node sever/index.js`. Seems like a simple typo?

Comment: I fixed the type on my package.json which now reads "dev": "node server/index.js" but I am still getting the same error message on the terminal

Comment: Hi Sean, I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

1. `npm cache clean --force` clean the npm cache
2. remove `node_modules` directory
3. I don't see `body-parser` in you `package.json`. install the package
4. In `inext.js` when you throw an `err`, pass the `err` variable to the function

and it should work.

Your index file:

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));

  server.listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on   ${PORT}`);
  });
});
```